# Issue with XML child nodes iteration when mix of text and element nodes

Tags: java, xml

I was trying to parse following  strings to form a xml document and then trying to extract all child nodes of  and add to a different document object which is already available to me.

```
<dhruba><test>this</test>that<test2>wang chu</test2> something.... </dhruba>

<dhruba>this is text node <test>this</test>that<test2>wang chu</test2> anything..</dhruba>
```

while I am trying to read the child nodes, it is returning null child for TEXT_NODE for 1st string and null for ELEMENT_NODE for 2nd String, this is wrong, is it API problem ??

I am using following code ... it compile , I am using java 6.

```
        Node n = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                try {
                    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                dom = db.newDocument();
                Element rootEle = dom.createElement("resources");
        // adding the root element to the document
        dom.appendChild(rootEle);

        Element element = dom.createElement("string");

        element.setAttribute("name", "some_name");
        try {

            n = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<dhruba><test>this</test>that<test2>node value</test2> some text</dhruba>"))).getDocumentElement();
            n = dom.importNode(n, true);


            NodeList nodeList = n.getChildNodes();
            int length = nodeList.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total no of childs : "+length);
            for(int count = 0 ; count < length ; count++ ){
                Node node = nodeList.item(count);
                if(node != null ){
                    element.appendChild(node);
                }
            }
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        rootEle.appendChild(element);
```

INPUT ::  as string

```
             <dhruba><string name="some_name">
                        that
                        <test>this</test>                             
                        <test2>node   value</test2>
                        some text
                     </string>
              </dhruba>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT ::  as document

```
               <string>
                 <string name="some_name">
                            <test>this</test>
                             <test2>node   value</test2>
                 </string>
              </string>
```

if I try to parse

```
          <test>this</test>that<test2>wang chu</test2> something....
```

then output comes as "thiswang chu"

```
Why is this happening?  what needs to be done if I want to add following node under another document element, i.e. <string>.
    <test>this</test>
                        that                             
                        <test2>node   value</test2>
                        some text 
[notice that it does not have <dhruba>] inside parent node of another 
document.
```

Hope I am clear. Above code compiles in Java 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want [`Node.cloneNode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#cloneNode%28boolean%29) method:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document dom = db.newDocument();

Element element = dom.createElement("string");
element.setAttribute("name", "some_name");

String inputXMLString = 
    "<dhruba><test>this</test>that<test2>node value</test2> some text</dhruba>";
Node n = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(inputXMLString))).getDocumentElement();
n = dom.importNode(n, true);

NodeList nodeList = n.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i)
{
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    element.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
}
dom.appendChild(element);
```

To get `dom` into stdout or file you could write:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(dom);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Result:

```
<string name="some_name">
<test>this</test>that<test2>node value</test2> some text</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that this is Java.

First, I'm surprised that you don't get an exception with your `importNode()` call, since you're importing the `Document`, which shouldn't be allowed (per the JavaDoc).

Now to the question that you asked: if you only want to attach specific node types, you need to make a test using the node's type. A `switch` statement is the easiest (note: this has not been compiled, may contain syntax errors):

```
switch (n.getNodeType())
{
    case ELEMENT_NODE :
        // append the node to the other tree
        break;
    default :
        // do nothing
}
```

Comment: No, importNode is returning the node, and if I add the parent noe i.e. <dhruba> instead of trying to add it's child nodes, it is adding fine and generating well formed output , but with <dhruba> parent element which I don't want. In addition, I need all type of nodes , TEXT_NODE or ELEMENT_NODE , so I didn't use the check, and surprisingly, it is returning null for either one of the node type according to given input.

Comment: @dhrubo: OK, in that case I have no clue what you're trying to do. I suggest that you edit your post to include a *complete*, *compilable* example. Then show input, actual output, and expected output. One thing that I can assure you, however: *it is **not** a problem with the API*.

Comment: Edited , please let me know if you need any further clarifications, and note the above code compiles. I am currently working with this code, I have just changed my variables.

Comment: And where do you define `dom`? When I say "compiles," I mean that I can copy your post into an editor window and actually compile it. As it stands, I can't do that. And seeing you do things like `dom.getParentNode().appendChild()`, where `dom` is almost certainly a `Document`, neither can you.

Comment: I am extremely SORRY, missed couple of line codes from a method. I think everything should be fine now for compilation.

Comment: @dhruba - you're the person with the bug, not me. And not the JDK. I'm willing to help you find that bug, but you have to show some effort. Your code still isn't compilable, and as I look at your sample output, it bears absolutely no relation to the code you show. If you decide to put the effort in, I'll take another look in about 10 hours. If not, best of luck.

Comment: I have corected the spelling mistale appendChild() , and apart from this , in my case the code is compiling fine. You can check my INPUT and EXPECTED OUTPUT. However the issue is resolved by using cloneNode() , suggested by Grzegorz Szpetkowski. He understood what I wanted. Anyway, thanks for your co-operation too.